# Как дать пользователям восстанавливать пароль?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

В проекте используется гем Devise.

При восстановлении пароля письмо генерируется нормально, ссылка с токеном, насколько я могу судить, тоже. Но, если перейти по этой ссылке, вижу:

> Started GET "/service/password/edit?reset_password_token=[FILTERED]"
>   for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-05-13 01:38:12 +0300 Processing by
>   Service::PasswordsController#edit as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "subdomain"=>""} Completed 401
>   Unauthorized in 1ms

в passwords_controller.rb есть:

```
prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication
append_before_action :assert_reset_token_passed, only: :edit
```

Куда копать?

Comment: В `flash[:alert]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Был не корректно указан класс в PasswordsController.

Было: `class User::PasswordsController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController`

Поменял на: `class User::PasswordsController < ::Devise::PasswordsController`